# Need to embed SSH terminal or a web based terminal in my Web application that can communicate and respond to the command I enter

Tags: web-applications, terminal, command-prompt, xtermjs

I am using Angular in my web appliation. For implementing terminal I have used https://xtermjs.org and *NgTerminal* component.
Using these two components I am able to show a Terminal window as shown in this demo https://qwefgh90.github.io/ng-terminal but that's nothing because it is not executing any command I enter.
I want this terminal to communicate with the computer and execute the command.

Ex: *If I enter ipconfig then the terminal should show the computer IP*

I have done lot of R&D and got an idea that it can be achieved using WebSocket, I used it but still no luck.

Thanks a lot for going through my issue, please share your valuable idea and suggestion so that I can create a responsive web terminal SSH. Thanks

Comment: You can't have this working on GitHub pages. You need a backend service where you have a real Unix-like system (like Linux) that will listen to commands and sent them back to the browser.

Comment: can please share the reference ? @jcubic

Comment: @cha1nsaw what do you mean by reference?

Comment: @jcubic I mean is there any material or code you can point me to, where I can implement the backend + frontend implementation of the above. thanks in advance

Comment: @cha1nsaw did you try to search? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=xterm.js+and+shell+backend+implementation&ia=web